# Iframe embed Office 365 excel : Refused to display link in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: html, sharepoint, iframe, office365

I made survey in office 365 excel, and I'm using below code to embed it to iframe:

```
<html>
    <body>
       <iframe scrolling="yes" src="https://my.sharepoint.com/personal/develop/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?guestaccesstoken=mNse3sc2%cLme20s%3d&docid=2_389e9fwgo21esd&wdFormId=%8C2396130B-CEBF-4D92-9307-0F9CF652C335%7D&action=formsubmit"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

But there's an error:

> Refused to display
>   'https://my.sharepoint.com/personal/develop/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?guestaccesstoken=mNse3sc2%cLme20s%3d&docid=2_389e9fwgo21esd&wdFormId=%8C2396130B-CEBF-4D92-9307-0F9CF652C335%7D&action=formsubmit'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

In the Office 365, I've modified the below settings:
In the Site settings => Site Collection Administration => HTML Field Security

[image]

Also, I tried following the instructions in this website:

http://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration/sharepoint-document-management/beyond-basic-integration/displaying-an-office-365-sharepoint-page-in-iframe/

But the error still exist, is there any settings I have to set?

Answer (score 1):

Going to a Documents library in my team site, I:

1. Clicked "New Document"
2. Chose "Excel Survey"
3. Created a Survey
4. Click "Share Survey"
5. Copied the link, in the style of **https://my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=E6AiBwKeMzs4TZkNRv9OAR0fyg9o1e%2bNEsa08VVvX5M%3d&docid=1_141f43de2c42b4f948d518137b2d5201b&wdFormId=%7BBB96539F%2D7A92%2D4D60%2D9DED%2D6284EBE30BCE%7D**
6. Used the Embed Code button in the ribbon bar to insert the survey in the page, and all is well.

The key difference I noted is that you seem to be using the Wopiframe URL (Office Web Apps) whereas the Share link I used here is different. Give it a try with the intended Share URL and see if that works for you.

Comment: is this only work in `read-only` mode?